# How to combine connlimit with IP sets?

Tags: iptables, ipset, netfilter

`connlimit` lets me limit the number of connections per client/service. How would I go about to combine such a rule with the IP sets available in more recent versions of the Linux kernel and netfilter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have an ipset named `MYTESTSET`, and that this ipset is of type `hash:ip`. It will store just ip adresses.

Then match against your IPset and after match against `connlimit` match extension, with the parameters you want.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp 
                   -m set --match-set MYTESTSET src
                   -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 --connlimit-saddr --connlimit-mask 32
                   -j DROP`

This will do the following: for each source inside the IP set, connections will be counted and if there is more than one (--connlimit-above 1), it will be droped, thus limiting the number of connection **per source in the ipset** to 1. (You can also match the other way, using `--connlimit-upto xxx` and `-j ACCEPT` instead of `DROP`)

If you want to consider the whole set and allow 1 connection **for all sources in the ipset** then set the `--connlimit-mask` switch to 0.